# Apache redirect and pass query string on to remote host

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

I'm hoping this is super easy for someone. I need to create a redirect in apache where...

```
http://something.com/a/1234567890 -> http://other.com/a/1234567890
http://something.com/a/8971347873 -> http://other.com/a/8971347873
```

But I have other URLs on something.com that begin with "a". So like...

```
http://something.com/afolder/folder/file.html
```

doesn't get redirected.

Can anyone help me real quick?

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect /a/ http://other.com/a/
```

See the Apache manual for [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).